# Detecting that iOS image data is HEIF or HEIC

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, heif

My server doesn't support the HEIF format. So I need to transform it to JPEG before uploading from my app.

I do this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];                                 
NSData *data=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

But how can I know that the data is HEIF (or HEIC) ? I can look at a file:

```
([filePath hasSuffix:@".HEIC"] || [filePath hasSuffix:@".heic"])
```

But I don't think it's a good answer. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 11):

Both existing answers have good recommendations, but to attempt to tell the whole story...

`UIImage` doesn't represent an *image file* or even *binary data in an image-file format*. A `UIImage` is best thought of as an abstract representation of the displayable image *encoded in* that data — that is, a `UIImage` is the result of the decoding process. By the time you have a `UIImage` object, it doesn't care what file format it came from.

So, as [@Ladislav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46831314/957768) notes, if you have a `UIImage` already and you just want to get data in a particular image file format, call one of the convenience functions for getting a `UIImage` into a file-formatted data. As its name might suggest, [`UIImageJPEGRepresentation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1624115-uiimagejpegrepresentation) returns data appropriate for writing to a JPEG file.

If you already have a `UIImage`, `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` is probably your best bet, since you can use it regardless of the original image format.

---

As [@ScottCorscadden implies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46977776/957768), if you don't have a `UIImage` (yet) because you're working at a lower level such that you have access to the original file data, then you'll need to inspect that data to divine its format, or ask whatever source you got the data from for metadata describing its format.

If you want to inspect the data itself, you're best off reading up on the HIEF format standards. See [nokiatech](https://nokiatech.github.io/heif/), [MPEG group](https://mpeg.chiariglione.org/standards/mpeg-h/image-file-format), or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format).

There's a lot going on in the HEIF container format and the possible kinds of media that can be stored within, so deciding if you have not just a HEIF file, but an HEIF/HEVC file compatible with this-or-that viewer could be tricky. Since you're talking about *excluding* things your server *doesn't* support, it might be easier to code from the perspective of *including* only the things that your server *does* support. That is, if you have data with no metadata, look for something like the JPEG magic number `0xffd8ff`, and use that to exclude anything that isn't JPEG.

Better, though, might be to look for metadata. If you're picking images from the Photos library with `PHImageManager.`[`requestImageData(for:options:resultHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phimagemanager/1616957-requestimagedata), the second parameter to your result handler is the [Uniform Type Identifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html) for the image data: for HEIF and HEIC files, `public.heif`, `public.heif-standard`, and `public.heic` have been spotted in the wild.

(Again, though, if you're looking for "images my sever doesn't support", you're better off checking for the formats your server *does* support and rejecting anything not on that list, rather than trying to identify all the possible unsupported formats.)

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to the party, but other than checking the extension (after the last dot), you can also check for the "magic number" aka file signature. Byte 5 to 8 should give you the constant "ftyp". The following 4 bytes would be the major brand, which I believe is one of "mif1", "heic" and "heix".
For example, the first 12 bytes of a .heic image would be:

`00 00 00 18 66 74 79 70 6d 69 66 31`

which, after removing 0s and trim the result, literally decoded to `ftypmif1`.

Comment: Actually, the first four bytes are: `00 00 00 28` as the fourth byte, the one right before `ftyp` is an opening parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

When you are sending to your server you are most likely decoding the `UIImage` and sending it as `Data` so just do

```
let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9)
```

Just decide what quality works best for you, here it is 0.9

Comment: Thanks. 
But how can I know that the data is HEIF (or HEIC) ? Just judge what's the suffix of file ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could look at magic bytes - JPEG and PNG certainly are known, and I seem to see some references that HEIF (.heic) starts with a NUL byte. If you're using any of the `PHImageManager` methods like `requestImageDataForAsset:options:resultHandler`, that resultHandler will be passed a `NSString * _Nullable dataUTI` reference. There's a decent WWDC video/slides on this (possibly [here](https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2017/511tj33587vdhds/511/511_working_with_heif_and_hevc.pdf)) that suggest if the UTI is not `kUTTypeJPEG` you convert it (and the slides have some lower-level sample code in swift to do it that preserve orientation too).

I should also mention, if you have control at your app layer and all uploads come from there, do all this there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `Photos` framework and are importing images from photo library, there's a solution that was mentioned briefly during WWDC17. First, import core services:

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

Then, when you request the image, check the `UTType` that is returned as a second parameter to your block:

```
// asset: PHAsset
PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: asset, options: nil) { imageData, dataUTI, orientation, info in
  guard let dataUTI = dataUTI else { return }
  if !(UTTypeConformsTo(dataUTI as CFString, kUTTypeJPEG) || UTTypeConformsTo(dataUTI as CFString, kUTTypePNG)) {
    // imageData is neither JPG not PNG, possibly subject for transcoding
  }
}
```

Other UTTypes can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mobilecoreservices/uttype/uti_image_content_types)